# Passing multiple params in an AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm playing around with AJAX calls. 
Ive tried so many different approaches, googled my goggles off and i'm kinda stuck.
I'm trying to pass multiple parameters through the ajax call that PHP can $_REQUEST.

```
$("#content").load("data2.php?page=" + this.id,hideLoader);
```

This picks up the id of a  item. and that works! it sends and I can $_request it on data2.php.

So I added class to that  and trying to pass it like this without luck:

```
$("#content").load("data2.php?page=" + this.id + "&category=" + this.class, hideLoader);
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: A small note, you should be using `$_GET`, not `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: have you tried escaping the & as &amp; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### OBJECT.class is invalid.

The correct one that your are looking for is:

### OBJECT.className

Thus your code should look like this:

```
$("#content").load("data2.php?page=" + this.id + "&category=" + this.className, hideLoader);
```

and also, deepening on your ajax initialization; in your PHP you should use `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: probably cause you guys thought of `$(this).class()` maybe.

Comment: thanks all of you and omeid! Works now and i picked up waaaay more ajax stuff because of it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the GET data as a separate parameter.

```
$("#content").load("data2.php", "page=" + this.id + "&category=" + this.className, hideLoader);
```

Also, since you know that this is GET, you should use `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

If you pass the data as an object, jQuery will use POST (`$_POST`).

```
$("#content").load("data2.php", {page: this.id, category: this.className}, hideLoader);
```

**EDIT**: As @Omeid said, `this.class` should be `this.className`.  Just remember that `this.className` will give you all the classes on an element, separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face this kind of Problem do an `alert` of `"data2.php?page=" + this.id + "&category=" + this.class` before calling load. e.g. first see the url before going there.

and use $_GET in your PHP code.